# Date display in Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, date

```
# date +"%b %d %H:$(( $(date +'%M')-5))"
Nov 20 12:45
```

```
date +"%b %d %H:$(( $(date +'%M')-55))"
Nov 20 12:-5
```

Why I am getting `-5` here? How to correct? Pls help.

Answer (score 6):

Probably because you ran it at 12:50, where `date +%M` gives you 50 which becomes 45 when you subtract 5 and -5 if you subtract 55.

At 12:00, you would have gotten -5 with the first one as well.

At 12:07, you would have gotten `12:2` instead of `12:02` and at 12:09, some shells would complain that `09` is not a valid octal number. You can't just subtract 5 to the minutes field to get the time 5 minutes earlier. Consider that for instance at `Jan  1 00:00`, it should give you `Dec 31 23:55`.

For date calculation on Solaris, you can use `perl` or `zsh` though the latter is not always installed by default. To get the time it was 5 minutes ago:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime("%b %d %R", localtime(time - 5*60))'
```

or:

```
zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/datetime; strftime "%b %d %R" $((EPOCHSECONDS - 5*60))'
```

Actually since version 11 of Solaris, `/bin/sh` and `/bin/ksh` are actually ksh93, so you could also use `ksh` there (better not `sh` as while `sh` is *currently* implemented by ksh93, that could change in the future and the standard `sh` language doesn't have those features):

```
ksh -c 'printf "%(%b %d %R)T\n" "5 minutes ago"'
```

As indicated by @glennjackman in comments, if you have `bash` installed, you could also do:

```
bash -c 'printf -v t "%(%s)T" -1 && printf "%(%b %d %R)T\n" "$((t - 5*60))"'
```

(support for `%s` and a recent enough version of bash was added in release 11 of Solaris as well).

And while we're at piling more languages, if you have a TCL interpreter, such as `expect`:

```
expect -c 'puts [clock format [
  clock add [clock seconds] -5 minute] -format "%b %d %R"]'
```

Or `python3`:

```
python3 -c 'import time; print(time.strftime("%b %d %R", time.localtime(time.time() - 5*60)))'
```

Comment: and starting in bash 4.2, you can write `printf '%(%b %d %H:%M)T\n' $(( $(printf '%(%s)T' -1) - 300 ))` -- what version of bash ships with Solaris 11, if any?

Comment: @glennjackman, (only if `$IFS` doesn't contain digits as you forgot the quotes). Are you sure `%s` is supported on Solaris (as that's not a standard `strftime()` directive)?

Comment: I don't have access to a Solaris machine to verify.

Comment: @glennjackman, from the [man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37843/strftime-3c.html#scrolltoc), looks like `%s` was added in Solaris 11 (*The conversion specifications for `%+`, `%P`, `%s`, `%OB`, and `%OV` and also optional flag characters and optional field width were added in the Solaris 11 and OpenSolaris releases for a better compatibility with other operating systems*). And it looks like Solaris 11 [now comes with bash-4.4 (optional package like for zsh)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/bash-1.html#scrolltoc)